# Cauchy's theorem and a contour integral

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\frac1{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma-i \infty}^{\gamma+i \infty} ds \, \frac{e^{-\sqrt{a s}}}{c s+s^{3/2}}  \cos{\sqrt{b s}} \, e^{s t}$$

where $a, b$ and $c$ constant. To evaluate this, I used Cauchy's theorem and considered the contour integral, but I think I have miscalculation, I could not find my mistake.

Comment: Could you write down your calculations? It is more likely that someone will respond, if we see your effort.

Comment: Is the $c$ in the denominator the same as in the integral limits ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom : Thanks! I edited it.

Comment: @MrYouMath : I will try to write down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inverse Laplace transform.  We assume $t \gt 0$; the ILT is zero when $t \lt 0$.

To evaluate, we consider the contour integral

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{a z}}}{c+\sqrt{z}} \cos{\sqrt{b z}} e^{t z} $$

where $C$ is a Bromwich contour which is detoured above and below the negative real axis and around the origin, as we define a branch cut of the square root there.  We define the branch cut by setting $-1=e^{i \pi}$ above the cut and $-1=e^{-i \pi}$ below the cut.

I will leave the details to the reader for now, but I get as a final result after applying Cauchy's theorem

$$\frac{c}{i 2 \pi} \int_{\gamma-i \infty}^{\gamma+i \infty} \frac{ds}{s} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{a s}}}{c+\sqrt{s}} \cos{\sqrt{b s}} e^{t s} = \\1-\frac1{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \left [\frac{\sin{\left (\sqrt{a} c x\right )}}{x} + \cos{\left (\sqrt{a} c x\right )} \right ] \cosh{\left (\sqrt{b} c x\right )} e^{-t c^2 x^2}$$

I will work on evaluating the integral on the RHS as time permits.  I suspect the final answer involves error functions of complex arguments, but I cannot say for sure right now.

Comment: Thank you Ron! How $c$ constant can be in arguments of $sin$, $cos$ , $cosh$ and $exp$? I could not understand that part.

Comment: @2che: I just rescaled the definite integral to neaten things up.

Comment: I am really sorry that I am asking this silly question, but how you can write $c$ in front of integral $$\frac{c}{i 2 \pi} \int_{\gamma-i \infty}^{\gamma+i \infty} \frac{ds}{s} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{a s}}}{c+\sqrt{s}} \cos{\sqrt{b s}} e^{t s}$$

Comment: Thinking of the avatar of OP (and yours), it was a question for you and you only!

Comment: @2che: because it was neater to write that way than to stick a $1/c$ in front of everything on the RHS.